# Swift crash with xib controls

Tags: ios, swift, xib, nib, nsobject

I'm trying to create some simple popup. It contains only 2 textfields and 2 buttons - "Cancel" & "Done". I've create separate `.xib` template and `NSObject` class.

This is how I init my class and load `.xib`:

```
class AddressPopup: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate
{
    private var originView: UIView!
    private var overlay: UIView!

    private var textFieldNumber: UITextField!
    private var textFieldStreet: UITextField!

    private var buttonDone:   UIButton!
    private var buttonCancel: UIButton!

    var rootView: UIView!
    var data = [String:String]()

    init(inView rootView: UIView, withData data: [String:String])
    {
        super.init()

        // Set basic data
        self.rootView = rootView
        self.data = data

        // Attach view
        self.originView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("AddressPopup2", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as? UIView
        self.originView.layer.cornerRadius = 5

        textFieldNumber = originView.viewWithTag(200) as UITextField
        textFieldStreet = originView.viewWithTag(201) as UITextField

        textFieldNumber.delegate = self
        textFieldStreet.delegate = self

        // Buttons
        buttonDone   = originView.viewWithTag(301) as UIButton
        buttonCancel = originView.viewWithTag(300) as UIButton

        buttonDone.addTarget(self, action: "buttonDoneAction", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    }
    // Other methods
```

And every time, when I'm trying to make one of textfield as first responder or tap on `done` button app crashes without any description. Just prints `(lldb)`. If I remove lines, where setting delegate to textfields -- all works fine. Or if I remove line with `addTarget` app doesn't crash.

I know that my text fields are not nil, because I can set some text. I can not figure out what caused the crash.

Comment: Maybe, you accidentally added a [breakpoint](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-source_editor/chapters/Creating,Disabling,andDeletingBreakpoints.html)?

Comment: I wish that the solution was so easy, but no.